# grails custom validator not stopping save

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a validator that is returning an error. The error even gets displayed through the flash messages. But the instance still saves. In the domain class I have...

```
static transients=['hasCustomErrors']

Boolean hasCustomErrors=false

static constraints={
  id validator:{val,obj->
    if(obj.hasCustomErrors){
        return 'errors.action.denied';
    }
   }

}
```

In a controller I have a test

```
   instance.message="This should not persist"
    instance.hasCustomErrors=true;
        if(!instance.hasErrors() && instance.save(flush:true)){
                //success message
                flash.messages.shift_tab=["Shift Was Successfully Flagged As Rejected"];

        }
        else{
            //error message
            flash.errors.shift_tab=[];
            instance.errors.allErrors.each{
                flash.errors.shift_tab.push(g.message([error: it]));
            }
        }

        redirect(action:'edit', id:params.id)
        return;
```

The view shows the error message, but the instance is still persisted so that the message column reads "This should not persist is' in the database.

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you may have to run `instance.validate()` before checking it has errors, I can see what you are trying to do and you can do it without introducing variables to capture errors instead make the instance reject

```
instance.errors.reject('fieldName','Issue with field')
```

That will force that field to fail